# React - Context issue - raphael-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, raphael

I am making a project using both React and Raphael and I am facing a context issue which somehow I do not manage to solve.

Simplified version of the code is as follow:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Raphael,Paper,Set,Circle,Ellipse,Image,Rect,Text,Path,Line} from 'react-raphael';

export default class PlanCdf extends React.Component {
 onmouseover(){
  console.log(this);
  console.log(this.props.project);
 }

 drawTasks() {
  return this.props.tasks.map((task) => {
   return <Path mouseover={this.onmouseover} key={task._id} d={coords} attr={{"fill":"#444444", "stroke-width" : "2"}} />
  })
 }

 render() {
  return(
   <Paper className={"paper"} width={this.state.paperWidth} height={this.state.paperHeight}>
    <Set>
     { this.drawTasks() }
    </Set>
   </Paper>
  )
 }
}
```

In my onmouseover function I'd like to access both context : The general context in order to access state and props and the Path context in order to change the attr of the path while onmouseover but somehow I always manage to get only one of the two.

I get either this context from path (like in example above) but can't access this.state.
Or if I bind I get the full this but not access to my path anymore.
.

Probably simple binding issue I don't get but can't manage to find a solution

--- EDIT ---

That's where I stand now:

```
    import React from 'react';
import {Raphael,Paper,Set,Circle,Ellipse,Image,Rect,Text,Path,Line} from 'react-raphael';

export default class PlanCdf extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.drawTasks = this.drawTasks.bind(this);
    }

    onmouseover(){
        console.log(this.state);
    }

    drawTasks() {
        return this.props.tasks.map((task) => {
            return <PathWrapper mouseover={this.onmouseover} key={task._id} d={coords} attr={{"fill":"#444444", "stroke-width" : "3"}} />
        })
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <Paper className={"paper"} width={this.state.paperWidth} height={this.state.paperHeight}>
                <Set>
                    { this.drawTasks() }
                </Set>
            </Paper>
        )
    }
}


export class PathWrapper extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    onmouseover() {
        console.log(this)
        this.attr({'stroke-width':'5'})
        this.props.mouseover()
    }

    render() {
        return <Path mouseover={this.onmouseover} d={this.props.d} attr={this.props.attr} />
    }
}
```

I can change the attr in the new PathWrapper component as suggested. but still nowhere can I access the state. I tried to call the function sent into the props to access the parent function but I can't as I need to be in the Path context to change the attributes... I more or less moved the pb to the child component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, problem solved. The Wrapper was not the right solution, but here you go for those interested:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Raphael,Paper,Set,Circle,Ellipse,Image,Rect,Text,Path,Line} from 'react-raphael';

export default class PlanCdf extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.drawTasks = this.drawTasks.bind(this);
    }

    onmouseover(raphael_context){
        console.log(this.state);
        raphael_context.attr({'stroke-width':'5'});
    }

    drawTasks() {
        return this.props.tasks.map((task) => {
            var self = this;
            return <Path mouseover={function() { return self.onmouseover(this) }} key={task._id} d={coords} attr={{"fill":"#444444", "stroke-width" : "3"}} />
        })
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <Paper className={"paper"} width={this.state.paperWidth} height={this.state.paperHeight}>
                <Set>
                    { this.drawTasks() }
                </Set>
            </Paper>
        )
    }
}
```

Now in onmouseover I have both access to the Path Raphael Object AND to the state of the parent !

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using React class you need to bind your methods in constructor or use arrow functions to bind to react context.

For accessing **"attr"** from **PlanCdf** component you can not do that from **"PlanCdf"** as it will be available in `props` of Path component (Child of **PlanCdf**).

I would suggest you to wrap `Path` in a component and then use the `this` context of that Wrapper component to get "`attr`" from passed props and then call onmouseover method from wrapper component, there you can access the "attr" from `this.props.attr`.

You may also need to store "`attr`" in local state of `PathWrapper` if you want to mutate it ( then your path wrapper component will not be functional component)

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Raphael,Paper,Set,Circle,Ellipse,Image,Rect,Text,Path,Line} from 'react-raphael';

export default class PlanCdf extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super(props);
    
    this.drawTasks = this.drawTasks.bind(this);
  }
 onmouseover(){
  console.log(this);
  console.log(this.props.attr);
    // Here you can the attr to a different color
 }

 drawTasks() {
  return this.props.tasks.map((task) => {
   return <PathWrapper mouseover={this.onmouseover} key={task._id} d={coords} attr={{"fill":"#444444", "stroke-width" : "2"}} />
  })
 }

 render() {
  return(
   <Paper className={"paper"} width={this.state.paperWidth} height={this.state.paperHeight}>
    <Set>
     { this.drawTasks() }
    </Set>
   </Paper>
  )
 }
}

const PathWrapper = ({mouseover, key, d, attr}) => {
  return (<Path mouseover={onmouseover} key={key} d={d} attr={attr} />);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Edit: Please look at below running code. I have removed rapheal for simplicity but all other things are same.

```js
 class PlanCdf extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           attr : {
                "backgroundColor":"#444444",
                "border" : "3px solid green"
           },
           oldattr : {
           }
        };
        this.drawTasks = this.drawTasks.bind(this);
        this.onmouseover = this.onmouseover.bind(this);
        this.onmouseout = this.onmouseout.bind(this);

    }

    onmouseover(){
    
       const newAttr = {
                "backgroundColor":"#444444",
                "border" : "1px solid green"
                };
       
       this.setState((prevState, props) =>  ({ attr : newAttr, oldattr : prevState.attr }));
    }

    onmouseout() {
      this.setState((prevState, props) => ({attr : prevState.oldattr, oldattr : prevState.attr }));
    }

    drawTasks() {
        return this.props.tasks.map((task) => {
            return <PathWrapper mouseover={this.onmouseover} mouseout={this.onmouseout} key={task._id} attr={this.state.attr} />
        })
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                { this.drawTasks() }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

 class PathWrapper extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return <div className="test" style={this.props.attr} onMouseOver={this.props.mouseover} onMouseOut={this.props.mouseout} > This is test </div>;
    }
}

const tasks = [{_id:1},{_id:2}];
ReactDOM.render(
  <PlanCdf tasks={tasks} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
.test {
   width: 100px;
   height:150px;
   border: 1px solid red;
   margin : 5px;
   padding : 5px;
   color : white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I feel we are in the right direction but it is sitll not working. I am editing question accordingly